# How to join the count(*) from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have a question here how to join the count(*) from another table to the underlying table.

The question is as following:

Table: Customer

```
+-------------+---------+
| Column Name | Type    |
+-------------+---------+
| customer_id | int     |
| product_key | int     |
+-------------+---------+
```

product_key is a foreign key to Product table.

Table: Product

```
+-------------+---------+
| Column Name | Type    |
+-------------+---------+
| product_key | int     |
+-------------+---------+
```

product_key is the primary key column for this table.

Write an SQL query for a report that provides the customer ids from the Customer table that bought all the products in the Product table.

For example:

Customer table:

```
+-------------+-------------+
| customer_id | product_key |
+-------------+-------------+
| 1           | 5           |
| 2           | 6           |
| 3           | 5           |
| 3           | 6           |
| 1           | 6           |
+-------------+-------------+
```

Product table:

```
+-------------+
| product_key |
+-------------+
| 5           |
| 6           |
+-------------+
```

Result table:

```
+-------------+
| customer_id |
+-------------+
| 1           |
| 3           |
+-------------+
```

The customers who bought all the products (5 and 6) are customers with id 1 and 3.

And my approach is:

```
select distinct 
c.customer_id 
from customer as c join (
    select 
    count(distinct product_key) as total 
    from product 
) as t 
group by c.customer_id 
having count(distinct c.product_key) = t.total
```

But I will encounter the error message as:

```
Unknown column 't.total' in 'having clause'
```

Would you mind figuring out where I did wrong? Thank you for your help in advanced.

Comment: I'm not sure you can reference a column in the subselect in a `HAVING` clause. "The SQL standard requires that HAVING must reference only columns in the GROUP BY clause or columns used in aggregate functions. However, MySQL supports an extension to this behavior, and permits HAVING to refer to columns in the SELECT list and columns in outer subqueries as well."

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] That includes DBMS version.

Comment: Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Thank you, @tadman. I am wondering if I refer to the outer subqueries in my code? I use the outer join to connect the original table, and the summarized count table.

Answer (score 1):

You do not require `HAVING` clause. You are attempting Cartesian join in your SQL. I doubt aggregation works well with Cartesian product.

Below SQL will return list of customers having all products -

```
select customer_id from (select customer_id, count(distinct p.product_key) product_count
from customer c 
join product p on c.product_key = p.product_key
group by c.customer_id) t
where t.product_count = (select count(distinct product_key) from product);
```

Comment: Thanks, Shantanu. That is my point. I am wondering why the aggregation doesn't work well in the join function.

Comment: Glad to help! pls accept it as answer and upvote so that it will be helpful for others experiencing  similar issue with aggregation.